# Obter todas as colunas de todas as tabelas que contenham um texto

Tags: sql, postgresql

Gostaria de descobrir quais são todas as colunas das tabelas de um banco de dados de uma forma que seja possível buscar uma palavra nessas colunas.

Digamos que tenha um banco de dados do qual não conheço a estrutura mas quero buscar uma palavra em todos as colunas do tipo `character varying` ou `blob` (acredito que só essas armazenam texto) sem precisar olhar uma por uma e ter que fazer a consulta manualmente.

Essa consulta também funcionaria em um banco de dados que tem diferentes `schemas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz essa função pensando na sua necessidade:

Basicamente seleciona todas as colunas de todas as tabelas do schema informado, e que são varchar ou text.

Depois percorre montando uma query, e retorna o resultado da query em uma tabela.

Como todas as tabelas tem estruturas diferentes, só retornei a coluna em questão, e o nome da tabela onde o valor foi encontrado:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.like_in_tables (valor varchar, sch varchar 
)
RETURNS table
(
coluna VARCHAR,
tabela varchar
)
 AS
$body$
    declare
       temprow record;
       cmd varchar;
       begin

       cmd := '';

        FOR temprow IN
        (
        select
x.table_name,
x.column_name
from information_schema.columns x
where x.table_schema = $2
and x.data_type in  ('character varying','text')
and x.is_updatable = 'YES'
         )
    LOOP
        cmd := cmd ||  ' SELECT '|| temprow.column_name ||'::varchar as coluna, '|| ''''|| temprow.table_name|| '''' ||'::varchar as tabela ' || ' FROM '|| temprow.table_name || ' where ' || temprow.column_name || '::varchar LIKE ' || '''' || $1 ||'''' || ' UNION '; 
    END LOOP;
        cmd := cmd || ' SELECT NULL, null ';

   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE cmd;   
       end;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
CALLED ON NULL INPUT;
```

Usando:

```
select * from like_in_tables('%LOPES%','public');
```

ou

```
select * from like_in_tables('LOPES%','public');
```

Answer (score 2):

Em `Postgres` essa informação pode ser obtida a partir do [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/information-schema.html), de uma `VIEW` chamada [`columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/infoschema-columns.html).

Por exemplo, considere as tabelas `tb_foobar` e `tb_xpto`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.tb_foobar
(
  id INTEGER,
  name CHARACTER VARYING(100),
  description TEXT,
  moment DATE,
  flag BOOLEAN,
  blah INTEGER,
  xpto NUMERIC(5,2)
);

CREATE TABLE public.tb_xpto
(
  id INTEGER,
  alpha CHARACTER VARYING(100),
  beta TEXT
);
```

Recuperando todas as colunas do tipo `CHARACTER VARYING` e `TEXT` de todas as tabelas do *schema* `public`:

```
SELECT
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  column_name,
  data_type
FROM
  information_schema.columns
WHERE
  table_schema = 'public' AND
  data_type IN ('text','character varying')
```

Saída:

```
| table_schema | table_name | column_name |         data_type |
|--------------|------------|-------------|-------------------|
|       public |  tb_foobar |        name | character varying |
|       public |  tb_foobar | description |              text |
|       public |    tb_xpto |       alpha | character varying |
|       public |    tb_xpto |        beta |              text |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/23840/2

Answer (score 1):

O *Workbench* tem essa funcionalidade, permite procurar um conteúdo em todas as tabelas usando `WbGrepData`.

O comando seria assim:

```
WbGrepData -searchValue=ValorProcurado -tables=public.* -types=table;
```

Aqui a documentação: http://www.sql-workbench.eu/wbgrepdata_png.html
Só não é possível especificar o tipo de columa, mas a busca será realizada em todas as colunas de todas as tabelas.